# Unable to hit the IBM mobile first server V7.1 - in some of the networks in Android devices

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am not able to hit my MFP adapters in some of the networks in Android devices alone. In iPhone, it is working perfectly fine.

We are getting this error:

> java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)

Have anyone faced this issue before?

Pasted details logs below: Masked the URL as "XXXXXXX"

```
02-19 20:33:30.100  24549-24549/com.Xpax D/cr_Ime? [AdapterInputConnection.java:234] updateSelectionIfRequired [0 0] [-1 -1]
02-19 20:33:30.101  24549-24549/com.Xpax D/cr_Ime? [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:74] updateSelection: SEL [0, 0], COM [-1, -1]
02-19 20:33:30.121  24549-24549/com.Xpax D/cr_Ime? [ImeAdapter.java:571] focusedNodeChanged
02-19 20:33:30.152  24549-24584/com.Xpax D/HttpPostRequestSender? WLHybridRequestSender.run in WLHybridRequestSender.java:42 :: Sending request "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
02-19 20:33:30.257  24549-24549/com.Xpax D/cr_Ime? [ImeAdapter.java:291] hideSoftKeyboard
02-19 20:33:30.257  24549-24549/com.Xpax D/cr_Ime? [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:56] isActive: true
02-19 20:33:30.258  24549-24549/com.Xpax D/cr_Ime? [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:65] hideSoftInputFromWindow
02-19 20:33:30.275  24549-24549/com.Xpax D/cr_Ime? [AdapterInputConnection.java:499] finishComposingText
02-19 20:33:53.355  24549-24584/com.Xpax E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin? WLNativeXHRPlugin$NativeXHRPostListener.onException in WLNativeXHRPlugin.java:177 :: onException
    java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterRecvfrom(IoBridge.java:592)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:556)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:485)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:37)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:237)
            at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
            at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:191)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:82)
            at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)
            at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:180)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)
            at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)
            at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:442)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:575)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:498)
            at com.worklight.wlclient.WLHybridRequestSender.run(WLHybridRequestSender.java:53)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
            at libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:161)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:250)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:553)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:485)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:37)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:237)
            at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
            at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:191)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:82)
            at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:174)
            at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:180)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:235)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:259)
            at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:279)
            at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:442)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:575)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:498)
            at com.worklight.wlclient.WLHybridRequestSender.run(WLHybridRequestSender.java:53)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
02-19 20:33:53.373  24549-24584/com.Xpax E/NONE? [/apps/services/api/Xpax/android/init] Host is not responsive. Try to manually access the URL through the android emulator browser to verify connectivity.
02-19 20:33:53.384  24549-24584/com.Xpax D/NONE? Failed connecting to MobileFirst Server.
02-19 20:34:27.359  24549-24549/com.Xpax D/cr_Ime? [ImeAdapter.java:213] updateKeyboardVisibility: type [0], flags [0], show [true]
02-19 20:34:27.359  24549-24549/com.Xpax D/cr_Ime? [AdapterInputConnection.java:178] updateState [] [0 0] [-1 -1] [true]
02-19 20:34:31.127  24549-24549/com.Xpax I/chromium? [INFO:CONSOLE(107)] "From invokeService FAIL: [object Object]", source: file:///android_asset/www/default/js/services/invokeService.js (107)
02-19 20:34:31.129  24549-24549/com.Xpax I/chromium? [INFO:CONSOLE(357)] "Inside Failure result = {"responseHeaders":{"Content-Length":"0","Connection":"Close","Date":"Fri, 19 Feb 2016 12:34:32 GMT"},"status":408,"responseText":"","invocationContext":null}", source: file:///android_asset/www/default/js/controllers/Login/loginCtrl.js (357)
```

Comment: It would be better to see wireshark logs of a successful request from iPhone and the same request failing in Android and compare.

Comment: Sure Thanks Idan. Let me compare and get back to you If I found anything

Comment: Any news regarding this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Verifying that a proper hostname is being used in wlclient.properties file (android\native\assets\wlclient.properties). It should not be "localhost" or a like, rather it should be the IP address of the host server.

Comment: Hi Idan, Sorry for the late reply. The issue was resolved. The problem is because of network issue and not code.